# Overriding Polymer's paper-input BiDi behavior

Tags: css, polymer, shadow-dom

I'm trying to use `paper-input` element in a complex BiDi application, and I need the input box to have a specific different `unicode-bidi` CSS setting in different settings.

I was trying to use CSS rules in my component that contains the `paper-input` element, but it doesn't have any effect on the the `paper-input` shadow-DOMed `INPUT` element - all my rules are being scoped to my element using a CSS class named after my element (or at least that's what Chrome's dev tools show), and while the top level `paper-input` element carries that class and can have my styles affect it, the internal `INPUT` element isn't - and I can't write rules to change its behavior.

Is there an official way to do what I'm trying to achieve, or will I have to re-create my own `paper-input` from scratch to support this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<paper-input>` contains a [`<paper-input-container>`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-input/paper-input-container), which supports a CSS mixin (`--paper-input-container-input`) that styles the inner `<input>`.

You could set the `<input>`'s `unicode-bidi` like this:

```
// dom-module
<template>
  <style>
    paper-input {
      --paper-input-container-input: {
        unicode-bidi: isolate;
      };
    }
  </style>

  <paper-input label="Name"></paper-input>
</template>
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo'
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.8.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <style>
        paper-input {
          --paper-input-container-input: {
            background: rgba(0,0,255,0.3);
            unicode-bidi: isolate;
          };
        }
      </style>

      <paper-input label="Name"></paper-input>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/NpBjRa?editors=1010)